# Debug > Windows > Output what does this console message mean?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've got a small, very simple, winforms which calls one class and is writing it's results to a console in Visual Studio's console window - the console called `Output`found in VSs `Debug` menu.

Some messages are automatically generated on the console and I am interested to understand what they mean; the following appears immediately after the information that the winforms wrote to the console - is this the thread that was doing the processing?

`The thread '<No Name>' (0x2280) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Screenshot of what I see in VS...

[image]

Comment: It's most likely just a ThreadPool thread being let go of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message means that a thread has ended but that shouldn't be a surprise.

I guess you want to know why threads are ending in your application even though you didn't create any new threads in your code. When using a framework like Windows Forms the framework will use threads to perform some additional work. These threads are normally taken from the .NET thread pool. What the thread has been doing before ending requires a bit more research though.

Comment: would it be very involved to give my program's thread a name ....so that I can see a name instead of `<No Name>` to prove all this to myself?

Comment: @whytheq: Your program has many threads. However, you are probably refering to the main thread or the UI thread when you are talking about "my program's thread". Depending on the configuration of your application exiting that thread will terminate the process. You will notice that and you don't really need to give that thread a name. To give a thread a name you need to create the thread in your code. Those anonymous threads terminating in the output window is most certainly threadpool threads that have completed some work.

Answer (score 1):

It show the threads currently being used to run your applycation as well as the threads running for the debugger. While the application is running the debugger can spawn new threads as well as end threads. When you see the thread exited with code 0, it means a normal exit was achieved that implied no errors.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the `Thread` message, a `Thread` that exists with `code 0` has succesfully completed all procedures. any other code would indicate `unhandeled exceptions`

the `headfirstPage204Farmer.vshost.exe` message is the executable which `Visual studio` uses to run the application

Answer (score 0):

Exited with code 0 usually means completed successfully (with no errors).

Answer (score 0):

It means that there was a thread, that correctly executed and returned `0`.
That is.

Answer (score 0):

Code 0 is good, its debug infoirmation that the process end as expected withno exceptions.